# RSpec test omniauth logout through Rails app with api only flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, omniauth, rspec-rails, google-oauth

I am creating a separate backend for my class project. I have a rails app with the api flag as I want to build this out to end points to be consumed with React or React Native. I was able to test authenticating or creating a user through the api endpoint. Now I'm trying to find a way to test the logout feature. I know how to check to make sure the login call back works. Without views to check for current path or page content, how can I test to ensure that the user is logged out successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this.

```
it 'can log out user' do
  get '/api/v1/auth/google_oauth2/callback', params: stub_omniauth
  user = JSON.parse(response.body)

  expect(request.session[:user_id]).to_not be_nil
  expect(user['name']).to eq('Rick Astley')
  expect(User.last.name).to eq('Rick Astley')

  get '/api/v1/signout'
  expect(request.session[:user_id]).to be_nil

end
```